# Deserializing json property with attribute returns null...C#

Tags: c#

Using NewtonSoft to do the deserializing.

I have the following JSON string

```
{\"PK\":\"test1@gmail.com\",\"SK\":\"read\",\"Role\":\"RLE#readonly\"}
```

I want to deserialize it to the following class:

```
public class UserDto
 {

    [JsonPropertyName("PK")]

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string SK { get; set; }

     public string Role { get; set; }

 }
```

When i run the folllowing:

```
var json = "{\"PK\":\"test1@gmail.com\",\"SK\":\"read\",\"Role\":\"RLE#readonly\"}";
var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(json);
```

All properties have values except Email which is null. I have the JsonProperty attribute but its still not working. How do I deserialize the PK JSON property to my Email C# property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said in the comment on your last post, pretty sure it's you mixing deserializers between system.text and the newtonsoft one. Try

```
public class UserDto
{        
    [JsonProperty("PK")]

    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your comment got lost in the other ones. That was it. Thanks

Comment: good, glad it helped. the alternative would be to keep the original attribute and use JsonSerializer.Deserialize<> instead